# Attempting to pass a custom attribute into react router (using v4)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have the following render method in my App.js:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <LocaleProvider locale={enUS}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <div>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path={home} component={requireAuth(Groups)} />
              <Route exact path={groups} component={requireAuth(Groups)} />
              <Route path={addcard} component={requireAuth(AddCard)} />
              <Route path={db} component={requireAuth(DbTbl)} />
              <Route component={NoMatch} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </LocaleProvider>
    );
  };
```

And I want to pass in a custom property to the first 2 routes ({home} & {groups}) so I'm attempting to do something like this:

```
 render() {
    const groups1 = () => <Groups studyState={this.toggleStudyState}/>;

    return (
      <LocaleProvider locale={enUS}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <div>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path={home} render={requireAuth(groups1)} />
              <Route exact path={groups} render={requireAuth(groups1)} />
              <Route path={addcard} component={requireAuth(AddCard)} />
              <Route path={db} component={requireAuth(DbTbl)} />
              <Route component={NoMatch} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </LocaleProvider>
    );
  };
```

But I'm getting this error message from react router:

> connectAdvanced.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a
>   function

So I suspect react router doesn't like the high order component syntax with the render= attribute. How can I pass the studyState attribute into the Groups component being used with the first two  tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [render](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) property must have a function passed to it. You are giving a Class.

Write something like that:

```
<Route exact path={home} render={(routerProps) => {
  const AuthGroups = requireAuth(Groups);
  return <AuthGroups studyState={this.toggleStudyState}/>;
}} />
```

As I don't know how the `requireAuth` works, I don't know if the `studyState` property will be properly passed to the `Group` component. But I guess it will.

---

Now to have a cleaner code (if the above solution works):

```
renderAuthGroups(routerProps) {
    const AuthGroups = requireAuth(Groups);
    return <AuthGroups studyState={this.toggleStudyState}/>;
}
render() {
    return (
        <LocaleProvider locale={enUS}>
          <Router history={history}>
              <div>
                  <Header />
                  <Switch>
                      <Route exact path={home} render={this.renderAuthGroups.bind(this)} />
                      <Route exact path={groups} render={this.renderAuthGroups.bind(this)} />
                      <Route path={addcard} component={requireAuth(AddCard)} />
                      <Route path={db} component={requireAuth(DbTbl)} />
                      <Route component={NoMatch} />
                  </Switch>
              </div>
          </Router>
      </LocaleProvider>
    );
};
```